# Partitions of Natural Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning, integer-partitions

This is a question from [Complex analysis by Stein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007K1BYD4).

The question is

Prove that it is not possible to partition $\mathbb N$ into finitely many infinite AP's with distinct common differences.(other than the trivial $a=d=1$)

Infinite AP:=$\{a,a+d,a+2d,......\}$.I have no idea as to how to approach it. Any hints are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you've written the question correctly?

Comment: What is wrong with $\{1, 3, 5, 7, \ldots\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots\}$?

Comment: @Hurkyl sorry forgot to add that common difference has to be different for all the infinite AP's which make up the partition. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I think the problem with your solution is that the common difference is 2 in both cases. Is that correct @happymath?

Comment: @Aal Right; the OP edited in the "distinct common differences" after my comment.

Comment: @happymath Should the intersection of two AP's be empty? If so, then I think I have a proof...

Comment: @Aal, the word, "partition", implies the intersections are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of proofs of this, but the complex-analysis tag points to D J Newman's proof. Corresponding to each arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,\dots$ is a generating function, $$x^a+x^{a+d}+x^{a+2d}+\cdots={x^a\over1-x^d}$$ To say the arithmetic progressions partition the natural numbers is to say the generating functions add up to $1/(1-x)$. This has a pole at $x=1$, and nowhere else. Now, consider the arithmetic progression with the greatest common difference --- call that common difference, $m$. Then the generating function for that AP will have a pole at $e^{2\pi i/m}$, which can't be cancelled by any of the other generating functions. So, we have a contradiction.

Comment: can you please share the other proofs as well

Comment: what is the proof that we cannot cancel out a pole because if the subsets are infinite then i think it is possible

Comment: Don't know them by heart, and they're a bit much to write out.

Comment: @happymath, there are only finitely many APs, only finitely many generating functions, no cancellation of that one pole.

Comment: $ \Sigma \frac{z^2^n}{1-z^2^{n+1}}=z/1-z $

Comment: @happymath, that's an **infinite** sum, yes?

Comment: i could not get it can you please explain why pole cancellation is not possible if there are finitely many of them

Comment: Exactly one of the generating functions has a pole at $e^{2\pi i/m$. Nothing else has a pole to cancel that pole.

Comment: Wow, that's a beauty.

Comment: For more work on this kind of problem, and references to other proofs, see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa50/aa5011.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is an old chestnut solvable by generating functions. For any infinite AP $\{a,a+d,a+2d, \dots\}$ consider the power series (generating function) $z^a + z^{a+d} + z^{a+2d} + \cdots$, which can be written as a rational function by summing the geometric series. The generating function for a disjoint union is the sum of the generating functions. So your hypothesized partition of $\Bbb N$ into infinite APs will give an expression for $x+x^2+x^3+\cdots = z/(1-z)$ (the generating function for $\Bbb N$) as a sum of these other rational functions. From there you should be able to derive a contradiction (which definitely requires something like the common differences are distinct...).